# External CD drive fail

Tags: hard-drive, cd

How to get rid of a malfunction, caused by a external CD-R/RW drive.
The drive worked pretty fine before.

It’s the same error at different divces and 'Operating Systems'.

Check the attachment at this post for the 'error prompt' by Windows.

[image: captured]

Comment: If it errors on all computers, it's dead, throw it away. You can get a new one for $£€ 10.

Comment: Try a new cable, if that doesn't work then trash it.